# Error 404 using MS Cognitive services Image Analysis demo code

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

Using the code from the MS Cognitive services example app at        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp I get Error 404 when trying to run the following code with imageFilePath set a local JPEG file:

```
static async void MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Request headers.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
        string requestParameters = "visualFeatures=Description&language=en";

        // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
        string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
            // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Execute the REST API call.
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            // Get the JSON response.
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Display the JSON response.
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(contentString));
        }
```

subscriptionKey is KEY1 from the two keys provided with my Azure subscription (in Eastern Australia location) and uribase is

```
const string uriBase = "https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0";
```

The combination of KEY1 and uriBase works OK with the demo of the API at

```
https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa/console
```

when the target file is a URL rather than a local file. The image is correctly analyzed.

Why am I getting the 404 error when trying to post from C#? Is it the fact that I am using content type application/octet-stream?

Code for GetImageAsByteArray is:

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
        return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
    }
```

Comment: The content type should be good as well as how you're sending the subscription key. What does `GetImageAsByteArray` look like? The docs have this - `byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the last portion of the request URI.  It should be:

`string uri = uriBase + "/analyze?" + requestParameters;`

Comment: This was it! Also I had to use KEY2 rather than KEY1 of my Azure subscription

Comment: Either key should have worked.  If you regenerate a key, it may take a bit of time for the front-end server to recognize it, which is maybe why only your key2 worked.

Comment: Another wrinkle was the presence of 2 await commands in MakeAnalysisRequest. Control was returned to calling routine after the 1st one, which was only posting the request, not the await receiving the response. Worked around it with a timer but not very elegantly

Comment: You'd want the `MakeAnalysisRequest` return a `Task` instead of `void`.  This will allow the caller to `await`.

Comment: My timer solution does not work when trying to call MakeAnalysisRequest from an asp.net web page . When an await function is executed control stops. Can you suggest any code examples for using  Image Analysis web servicefrom a web app? All examples I can find are from Windows apps.